# Can I do IOS development using ionic on Windows?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

**Are there ways to develop IOS applications in Windows?**

I am thinking of going with IONIC framework because I need to build both Android and IOS Apps. If necessary, OS X will be installed on virtualbox but not sure whether it is a good idea.

Could anyone give advice? Thank you. :)

Comment: NO you can not. iOS development requires Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched enough and received feedback from others that to implement IOS Apps using IONIC, **MAC is essential**.

Virtual OS is also possible but by my own experience (installed few times with different version of OS) and hearing from others, it is **NOT recommended** due to its **stability**.

OS X on virtual machine was very laggy and OS behaved faulty so I had to reboot the OS repeatedly.